# Why Magento Better than Wordpress

Tags: magento2, wordpress

Any Help Regarding to this highly Appriciated.

I see wordpress is light weight , fast and easy to work on it more over very cheap hosting like shared hosting is compatible for wordpress however also have very low amount of bugs

when i compared with Magento. Magento is High Level of coding, complex to install, and very complex CLI interface and and very slow than wordpress, and also need expensive hosting..

i need to know the difference between them please only reliable answer

Answer (score 0):

First, of, **Magento** is completely different from **Wordpress**.
**Magento** is an e-commerce platform while **WordPress** is a CMS platform built specifically for content management like blogs.

Although WP has an e-commerce plugin called **woocommerce,** Magento still is more reliable to use when you are building an **extensive e-commerce webshop** because Magento is built with all the features of eCommerce software that surely a CMS specific platform like WordPress doesn't have. Magento is designed for building large eCommerce webshops. Its architecture is by far the most comprehensive in all the eCommerce platform because of its **multi-store** management functionalities. Inventory, Sales and Order Management also are highly scaled and more dynamic.

For me, if we are in to an eCommerce wise platform regardless of hosting cost and other external stuff but more of scalability, strong B2B eCommerce capabilities, complete eCommerce features, and functionalities, powerful, Secure, comprehensive and Highly Adaptable, I'll go with Magento.

Comment: but magento have many bugs while developing website.. even we can't un install module or theme from it in case change of design. the upgration in magento is much complicated things. where as in wordpress 1 click in 5 seconds wordpress update.

Comment: Do you mean woocommerce? It's up to you basically, like I have said above when you are into building a more dynamic and comprehensive eCommerce website, better to go with Magento because of its full packed eCommerce features. It's built for small to large, Business to business e-commerce shops. Whereas in woocommerce, it is for small webshops only and has a limited eCommerce functionalities like multi-store feature wherein you have to purchase plugins unlike in Magento it is built in functionality already.

Comment: The capacity of Magento as a webshop platform is comprehensive as Ive said in terms of its scalability. Magento can handle large number of inventories, orders management and so on. If you plan or envision your web shop to be grow big in the long run Magento is a good choice. It's database structure as well is solid

Comment: But as you have said, it's only downside is the learning curve since it has a bit complicated setup compared to woocommerce that's why it is still up to you on what is your requirement on building a webshop. My say is, Magento is a solid eCommerce software, more niche, built specific to perform an eCommerce solutions